# How to write a query in PostgreSQL to accumulate items throughout joining?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

we have a spatial database which contain ways (streets, alleys, highways...) as multiple segments, e.g. each street is broken into several rows in which we have its nodes (as geometry) and name. We want to have another table containing joined ways with their name and nodes. We must recursively join ways table with itself on having common node, and then accumulate (aggregate) nodes and id's into arrays. I tried several ways to create a true query for this with no success: I tried to use recursive with alongside with join. I also tried to use lateral join. I guess I have to mix several techniques for that. here is my (wrong) query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE result(id1, id2, ids, "name", nodes) AS
(SELECT
w1.id                AS id1,
w2.id                AS id2,
ARRAY [w1.id, w2.id] AS ids,
w1.name              AS name,
w1.nodes || w2.nodes AS nodes
 FROM
  (SELECT
    id,
    ways.name,
    nodes
FROM ways
WHERE ways."name" IS NOT NULL AND tagshstore ? 'highway') w1
JOIN
(SELECT
  id,
  ways.name,
  nodes
FROM ways
WHERE ways."name" IS NOT NULL AND tagshstore ? 'highway') w2
 ON
   w1.nodes && w2.nodes
   AND
   w1.name = w2.name
   AND
   w1.id < w2.id)

SELECT
  result.name AS "name",
  array_agg(ways.id) || result.ids as ids,
  array_agg(result.nodes)
--INTO ways_connected
FROM result
  JOIN ways
    ON result.name = ways.name AND result.nodes && ways.nodes
GROUP BY result.ids, result.name;
```

Comment: Without sample data, your question really lacks sufficient information for some else to understand.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Teh data is from OSM standard database. (Open Street Map)

Comment: Note: the `WHERE ways."name" IS NOT NULL` are not needed, since you are joining on `name`.